# Include exec files in osx app bundle

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode6, resourcebundle, nsbundle

Ive looked around a bit and cant find the answer I was hoping for, I am new to OSX dev so forgive me if this is a basic question.

Using `NSTask` I open up an exec file while my OSX is running that does stuff, I have to set a launchPath for this like so `self.execFile.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/execFile";`. This is fine when I'm running it on just my Mac, however, I would like to distribute this app. I am looking for a way to to save the execFile in, from what I gather so far from Googling, the apps bundle and call it from there, that way I can set the launchPath in the code and it would work on any computer. So far Ive only seen talk on how to access the app bundle but I don't know how to save a file there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a Copy Files build phase for your application target and add the exec files to the Copy Files build phase. Select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select your application target from the left side of the project editor. Click the Build Phases button at the top of the editor. Choose Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Copy Files Build Phase to add the Copy Files build phase.

After creating the Copy Files build phase, click the disclosure triangle next to it. From there you can add files to the build phase and choose a location in the app bundle to copy the file. When you build the project, Xcode copies the files in the Copy Files build phase to the app bundle in the location you specified.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. Now i'm curious, do you know of a way I can add a file to the app bundle that wont be visible to users if they decide to "show package contents"

Comment: I don't know of a way. Files whose names start with a period are initially invisible in the Finder, but there are ways to make hidden files visible in the Finder. If someone really wants to look at the files in your app bundle, there's not much you do to stop them.

Comment: I see, I know implementation and header files written in Xcode itself like AppDelegate.m/.h and what not don't show up in the bundle so I was hoping to have a .js file just hidden in there as well. I might just have to rethink my code, thanks again